# Uploading Media through Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm a student home from summer break creating an application and I'm stuck. I cant figure out what field to use when passing an image through my post form. Would it just be a StringField referencing the image on my os, and use the same string on my sqlite3 database? Would I be using the same reference to display it in html through jinja? Everything works fine, no debugger screen when i submit posts with an image, but the image is not loading to the database.

## Here is the route:

```
@posts.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@login_required 
def new_post(): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        photo = request.files.get('photo') 
        content = request.form.get('content' if not (photo and content): 
            flash('You must fill in all the fields', 'caution') 
    elif: 
         try: 
             filename = uploaded_photos.save(photo) 
         except UploadNotAllowed: 
             flash('Upload type unpermitted', 'danger') 
    else: 
        post = Post(content=content, filename=filename) 
        db.session.add(post) 
        db.session.commit() 
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success') 
        return redirect(url_for('main.home')) 
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='Create Post',form=form, 
    legend='Create Post')
```

## Here is the model:

```
class Post(SearchableMixin, db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['content']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    # photo = ?
    # video = ?
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.content}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

## And here is the form in question...

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField 
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class PostForm(FlaskForm): 
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()]) 
    submit = SubmitField('Post') 
    # photo = ?
    # video = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileField` is definitely a better options for images.

The [docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html) go through an example that would be very helpful with what you are trying to accomplish.